# jquery change value of input created after page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I simply need to change the value of the input field which is created on button click. I have tried the below but it gives me undefined error since the element was not there when the page loaded. any ideas?

```
$('#test').val("test");
```

I use the below code for click event but I have no idea how to do the same thing for the above one too

```
$('body').on("click", ".btnx", function() {
    //do something
});
```

Comment: That code can't give you an error. Using a selector that doesn't find anything isn't an error, and using the `val` method on an empty jQuery object isn't an error. What does actually happen? When and why is the element created, and why can't you set the value for it when that happens?

Comment: @Guffa it might not be an error but I assumed it was since it showed `undefined`. When I do `alert($('#test').val())` I get undefined. The input already has a value. I am using bootstrap popover and that's why the input is created after the page loads

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#test').click(function(){
    //code here
});
```

Comment: I don't think you understand the question. I don't have a button, I have a input field and want to change the value. I included the click part just to show how it works on buttons created after the page loads.

Comment: Maybe I worded the question wrong but I have bootstrap popover which contains an input box and I'm trying to change it's value. The input shows up when I click a button and that's what I meant by created after page loads.

Comment: The page isn't loading though, the input is just generated after clicking the button? so you could use the click event of the button to change it's value.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#test').empty();
$('#test').append('test');
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't anything like delegated events when you want to set the value of an input that is added out of your control, because there is no event to wait for.

You can wait for the element to come into existance, and set the value when it's there:

```
var handle = window.setInterval(function(){
  var i = $('#test');
  if (i.length) {
    i.val('test');
    window.clearInterval(handle);
  }
}, 100);
```

The interval 100 means that it checks ten times per second, so it may be as long as 1/10th of a second after the element is created that the value is changed. You can adjust the value depending on how fast you need the value to be set, and how much overhead you can allow.